# How do I not create a new document if the previous document in the collection contains a certain value?

Tags: python, faunadb

I am using the python library to programmatically create documents in a collection as such:

```py
user = client.query(q.create(q.collection("my_collection"), {
             "data": {
                     "UTC_datetime": str(datetime.now(pytz.UTC)),
                     "item_one": str(value_one),
                     "item_two": str(value_two),
                     "item_three": str(value_three)
         }
     }))
```

Upon certain conditions being met the python app executes again.

If `item_two` on the next app execution has the same value again I **do not** want a new document to be created.

How do I craft the above query to perform this?

Currently, I am reading the previous document, extracting the value from `item_two` and performing an if/else statement to either proceed to store a new document or `sys.exit()`.

I'm positive there is a more elegant solution that is based within Fauna's logic instead of Python's, however, I have not been able to achieve this.

Comment: You can create a unique index  for item_two to ensure that duplicates are not possible. You may also want to try an upsert implementation https://forums.fauna.com/t/multi-document-upsert/488/3

https://forums.fauna.com/t/does-fauna-supports-upserts/208

Answer (score 2):

You can create a unique index (https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/indexes) for item_two to ensure that duplicates are not possible. You may also want to an upsert implementation

https://forums.fauna.com/t/multi-document-upsert/488/3

https://forums.fauna.com/t/does-fauna-supports-upserts/208

```
q.If(
   q.Exists(q.Match(q.Index('unique_item_two'), str(value_two))), 
   q.Update(...),
   q.Create(...)
)
```